# How to position an absolute label, underneath a button and centered in the div

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to achieve this layout: [image]

I have this:

```
  <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button>
            <i></i>
        </button>
        <label>Carregamento Telemóvel</label>
   </div>
```

My label has to be `absolute` positioned because it can't take space in the `div`. The `div` has to be the width of the button.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry guys, my question was done in a little bit of hurry, so it was incomplete. I will now explain detailed.

1. I need all the div's to be responsive and don't have a fixed width.
2. The button itself it's contained in a row with others button's with the same layout.
3. The button's have to have the same margin between them, that's why I can't have the label with with because the length of the text it's never the same so the div's will have different sizes, and then I can't give the same margin between them.

Solution:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NYOb3uQnYrNFkfO6RaIG?p=preview

The plunker just works in -webkit- but it's all I need.

Comment: Could you share the CSS & HTML you have so far in a JSFiddle so we can better help you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to centering the label is a CSS3 transform

```
.button-wrapper label {
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.button-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.button-wrapper i {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  width: 1.4em;
  border-radius:50%;
  display: block;
}

.button-wrapper label {
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">

  <i>K</i>

  <label>Carregamento Telemóvel</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This code work's if it is only an item in row, but without the top and left property's I could achieve what I wanted, so I will put this as my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```css
.button-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.button-wrapper > button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px; width: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  border: 0 none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.button-wrapper > button > i {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.button-wrapper > label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
        <button>
            <i></i>
        </button>
        <label>Carregamento Telemóvel</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't limit the width of the wrapper. Because of it's contained in a row of items.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to help you. But you can center an absolute positioned block element by combining `margin:0 auto; left:0; right:0;`

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vfs3n68e/

Answer (score -1):

Here's a very simple way to do it that I've created quickly: https://jsfiddle.net/rn8ysg5q/

HTML:

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button>
    <i></i>
  </button>
  <br />
  <label>Carregamento Telemóvel</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button-wrapper
{
    /*border: 1px dotted red;*/
    color: orange;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Reset button layout */
.button-wrapper button
{
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    color: inherit;
    /* cursor: default; */
    font: inherit;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* for input */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* for button */
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;    
}

.button-wrapper button
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

If that's what you're looking for I'll update it once I'm home in an hour and make some improvements.

Comment: My question is a little incomplete, but I can't specify a width on the wrapper.